# Yacc, Syntax error in line 1 always except when blank input

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex

I've tried to make a mini c compiler with the help of lex and yacc

Below is the yacc/bison code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern FILE *fp;

extern int line;
extern int yylex();
int yyerror(char *);
%}

%token FOR WHILE IF ELSE PRINTF NUM ID STR ROP LOG INC RETURN STRUCT INT      FLOAT CHAR DOUBLE VOID LT GT LE GE NE EQ

%right '='
%left LOG
%left AND OR
%left LT GT LE GE NE EQ
%left '+' '-'   
%left '*' '/' '%'
%left INC

%nonassoc XYZ
%nonassoc ELSE

%%

start: Function start
  | Declaration start
  |
  ;

Declaration: Type Ass ';'
   | Ass ';'
   | Type Arr ';'
   | Arr ';'
   | StructStmt ';'
   | FunctionCall ';'

   ;

Ass: ID1 '=' Ass
| ID1 '=' FunctionCall
| ID1 '=' Arr
| Arr '=' Ass
| ID1 ',' Ass
|  NUM ',' Ass
| ID1 '+' Ass
| ID1 '-' Ass
| ID1 '*' Ass
| ID1 '/' Ass
| ID1 '%' Ass
| NUM '+' Ass
| NUM '-' Ass
| NUM '*' Ass
| NUM '/' Ass
| NUM '%' Ass
| RETURN Ass
| '\'' Ass '\''
| '\"' Ass '\"'
| '(' Ass ')'
| '-' ID1
| '-' NUM
| INC ID1
| ID1 INC
| INC NUM
| NUM INC
| ID1
| NUM
;

ID1: ID
;

FunctionCall: ID1 '(' Ass ')' 
    | ID1 '(' ')'
    ;

Function: Type ID1 '(' ArgListOpt ')' Stmt
 ;

ArgListOpt: ArgList Arg
  |
  ;

ArgList: ArgList ',' Arg
   | Arg
   ;

Arg: Type ID1
 ;

CompoundStmt: '{' StmtList '}'
      ;

StmtList: StmtList Stmt
|
;

Stmt: WhileStmt
| ForStmt
| IfStmt
| CompoundStmt
| Declaration
| PrintFunc
| ';'
;

PrintFunc: PRINTF '(' STR ',' Ass ')' ';'
 | PRINTF '(' STR ')' ';'
 ;

WhileStmt: WHILE '(' Expr ')' Stmt
 ;

ForStmt: FOR '(' Expr1 ';' Expr1 ';' Expr1 ')' Stmt
   ;

Expr1: Expr
 | 
 ;

IfStmt: IF '(' Expr ')' Stmt %prec XYZ
  | IF '(' Expr ')' Stmt ELSE Stmt
  ;

StructStmt: STRUCT ID1 '{' Type Ass '}' 
  ;

Expr: Expr LE Expr 
| Expr GE Expr
| Expr NE Expr
| Expr EQ Expr
| Expr GT Expr
| Expr LT Expr
| Expr LOG Expr
| Ass
| Arr
;

Arr: Type ID1 '[' Ass ']'
; 

Type: INT
| FLOAT
| CHAR
| DOUBLE
| VOID
;

%%

#include <ctype.h>
#include "lex.yy.c"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen("tests/test1.c", "r");  
    if (!yyparse())
    {
        printf("Success\n");
    }
    else
    {
         printf("Error\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int yyerror (char *s)
{
    printf("%d : %s %s\n", line, s, yytext);
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the lex file which I've used to collect the tokens

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int line = 1;
%}

L [a-zA-Z_]
D [0-9]

%x mcomment  
%x slcomment

%%

"/*"    BEGIN(mcomment);
"//"    BEGIN(slcomment);


<mcomment>"/*"  printf("Error Mcomment");
<mcomment>. ;
<mcomment>\n    line++;
<mcomment>"*/"  BEGIN(INITIAL);
<slcomment>.    ;
<slcomment>\n   {line++; BEGIN(INITIAL);}

"printf"    return PRINTF;
"for"   return FOR;
"while" return WHILE;
"if"    return IF;
"else"  return ELSE;
"return" return RETURN;
"struct" return STRUCT;
"int" return INT;
"float" return FLOAT;
"char" return CHAR;
"double" return DOUBLE;
"void" return VOID;

{L}({L}|{D})*   {return ID;}
{D}+([^{L};])*  {return NUM;}
"+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"%" {;}
"=" {;} 
"<="    return LE;
">="    return GE;
"=="    return EQ;
"!="    return NE;
">" return GT;
"<" return LT;
"!" ; 
"&&"|"||"   {return LOG;}
"++"|"--"   {return INC;}
\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"   {return STR;}
^"#include ".+  ;
^"#include".+   ;
"("|")"|"["|"]"|"{"|"}" {;}
[ \t]   return yytext[0];
";" ;
\n  {line++;}
.   return yytext[0];

%%
```

No matter which file I give as input, it always shows a syntax error in line 1. It shows successful parsing only when I give a blank input file, which is useless.
Is there a problem with the grammar?
Or is the lex code wrong?

Comment: Strange grammar. `start` should be left-recursive, as should all other recursive productions. `Ass` allows `a = RETURN a;` among other nonsense. I suggest you clean it up to properly express your intentions.

Comment: @EJP left recursion adds 7 shift-reduce conflicts plus one supposedly useless grammar (NULL of ArgListOpt) which is actually very useful

Comment: So fix them. Your productions are largely nonsense anyway, as I already indicated. Right recursion adds stack overflows at runtime. Which do you really prefer?

Answer (score 1):

Your lexer returns all white space characters as themselves, except for newlines, which it eats (does not return).

Your grammar accepts *no* white space characters.  So if you have any white space in your input stream, there will be a syntax error.

Your grammar generally requires semicolon terminators, but your lexer eats semicolons (does not return them).  So if you have any productions that must end with a semicolon, there will be a syntax error here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar is expecting whitespace to be ignored and semicolons to be sent as `';'` tokens. Your lexer, on tbe other hand:

```
[ \t]   return yytext[0]; // Send every soace and tab as a token
";" ;                       // Ignore semicolons
```

You also ignore arithmetic operators. Undoubtedly there are other problems as well.

Suggestion: since this is your very first bison/flex project, start with something much simpler and work up to a full grammar a little bit at a time. Make extensive use of flex's trace facility (just add `-d` to the command line which processes your lex file.)

Good luck.